# Checking if the user is still on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

How do you check if the user is still on the same page?

I want to mark a post if any user has been reading the same post for longer than five minutes. To do this, I need to check twice: when he first reads the post, and when 5 minutes have passed. Right now, I'm thinking of doing..

1. Give a reader a `session[post_id]` when he first reads a post.
2. Use `delayed_job` to see if the user still has the session after 5 minutes. If he does, I mark the `post`
3. Whenever he goes back to the list of posts, I check whether he has any `session[post_id]` and get rid of it.

Does this logic make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a javascript to trigger a request:

```
<script>
  $(document).on('ready', function(){
    this.setTimeout(function(){
      $.post("/posts/update/#{@post.id}", {marked: true})
    }, 1000*60*60*5)
  })
</script>
```

Comment: But this can't be integrated into the backend code, can it? How can I mark a post this way? (e.g. `@post.marked = true`)

Comment: @Maximus - You have to send an Ajax request on the setTimeout function

Comment: What if my method requires a bit more complex request? Each `post` has_many `readers`, and I want to add the `current_user` to the list. Could this be achieved by posting an ajax request?

Comment: Basically, any thing that the user can achieve by clicking on a link, or submitting a form can be done with js. For the second part add callback to the post model. Keep the logic within your app, there's no need to make complex hacks.

Comment: I think I will be able to work it out from this point. I will let you know if I am stuck later.